# Azure Linux App Service : Installing packages after deploy from Devops pipeline

Tags: linux, azure, yaml, azure-web-app-service, devops

I'm currently setuping a CI/CD pipeline in Azure Devops to deploy a NodeJS app on a linux hosted app service (not a VM).

My build and deploy both go smoothly, BUT I need to make sure some packages are installed in the environment after the app has been deployed.

The issue is: whatever `apt-get` script I create after the deploy, I have to run then manually for them to actually take effect. In the Pipeline log they seem to have been executed, though.

Here is the part of my yaml code responsible for the deploy, did I miss something?

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    workspace:
      clean: all
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy:'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|16-lts'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/drop$(Build.BuildNumber).zip
              startUpCommand: 'pm2 start index.js --no-daemon'
        on:
         success:
           steps:
           - script: sudo apt-get update
             displayName: apt update
           - script: sudo apt-get -y [SOME LIBS] 
             displayName: try install dependencies
```

Thanks !

Comment: Why would you try to install dependencies after deploying the app?

Comment: Because there are linux packages which are not by default in the environment, but needed to run some NPM packages. 
For instance it is puppeteer which only works once I execute this command: 
"apt-get -y install libglib2.0-0 libgconf-2-4 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgbm-dev libnss3-dev libxss-dev libasound2"

And since each deploy resets the env, I need it to be run once the app is deployed, preferably not manually.

Comment: To keep it simple you can add those commands in the startUpCommand. Also, you can use docker containers. Docker will give you more flexibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, went with a "startup.sh" file which I run manually after each deploy. Gonna go through docker later though

Comment: Have you found any solution on this or are you still running the script manually each time?

Comment: luckily that is a service we deploy very rarely. but unless you go through docker, that is the only solution i've got